# Jump values in loop "for"

Tags: java

I have two "for" loops.

```
for(n=0;n<6;n++){
for(w=n;w<6;w++){
// if w==4 then go to first loop an continue from n=4!!
}
}
```

How can i jump to n=4 when w takes value 4; Like old Basic command "goto"..
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [break statement?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: One wonders what algorithm requires this kind of loop logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i jump to n=4 when w takes value 4; Like old Basic command
>   "goto"

You can use `break` to "jump" out of the current loop back to the outer loop:

```
for(n=0;n<6;n++){
    // other code
    for(w=n;w<6;w++){
    // if w==4 then go to first loop an continue from n=4!!
        if (w == 4) {
            n = 4;
            break;
        }
    }
    // other code
}
```

Comment: and then we have an infinite loop as w remains at 4 forever

Comment: it doesn't create an infinite loop.

Comment: @clcto: you are right, n actually goes to 4++ = 5, and therefore w as well. (but then does it really answer the question?)